# How to remove values from object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have stored arbitary data in an object as:

```
    $(".cat-list-table tr td").live("click",function(){
       if($("body").data($(this).html())){
            delete $("body").data().$(this).html(); // I am want to delete value if already exists 
      }else{
          $("body").data($(this).html(),$(this).html());
      }
   });
```

now I want to remove duplicate values .

any idea how to remove values from object.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to clear the data in the body they you can use
`$("body").html("");` 
this will clear the contents inside body

Comment: Holy crap, are you using the entire HTML as a ***key*** **and** a value in data() ?

Comment: @adeneo nothing crap it is just <td>word</td> if I click on <td> It gives me the word! & not whole page & dont you see a word this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`removeData` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/):

```
$("body").removeData($(this).html());
```